# how do i return new promise from a function with local values passed as parameters?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to return promise.all() with sources variable locally defined below so i could consume the promise  when i call sourceRequest.then((sources)=>{//do something})
here's my code:

```
var sourceRequest=(...countries)=>{
    var sources=[];
    var promisesCollection=[];
    for(var country of countries)
    {
      var promise=this._vm.$axios.get('/sources',{params:{ country,language:'en'}})
      .then(response=>{
        sources.push(response.data.sources);
      });
      promisesCollection.push(promise); 
    }

    Promise.all(promisesCollection).then(()=>{
      return new Promise((resolve)=>resolve(sources));
    })
  };
  sourceRequest('in').then((sources)=>console.log(sources));
```

The problem is i get undefined in console
**The workaround:**
i have a workaround to this but the problem is i want the function to return sources and not api requests responses:

```
//this works
  var sourceRequest=(...countries)=>{
    var promisesCollection=[];
    for(var country of countries)
    {
      var promise=this._vm.$axios.get('/sources',{params:{ country,language:'en'}})
      promisesCollection.push(promise); 
    }

    return Promise.all(promisesCollection);
  };

   sourceRequest('in').then((response)=>{console.log(response)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `sourceRequest`, so it returns `undefined`, not a Promise.

While you could fix it by returning the `Promise.all`:

```
return Promise.all(promisesCollection).then(() => {
```

It would be more elegant to avoid the [explicit Promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) as well. Map the responses to their `.data.sources`:

```
const sourceRequest = (...countries) => {
  const promisesCollection = [];
  for (const country of countries) {
    promisesCollection.push(this._vm.$axios.get('/sources', {
        params: {
          country,
          language: 'en'
        }
    }));
  }

  return Promise.all(promisesCollection).then(
    responsesArr => responsesArr.map(response => response.data.sources)
  );
};
sourceRequest('in').then(console.log);
```

Or, with `.map` *alone*, instead of a `for` loop:

```
const sourceRequest = (...countries) => {
  return Promise.all(countries.map(country => (
    this._vm.$axios.get('/sources', {
        params: {
          country,
          language: 'en'
        }
    })
      .then(response => response.data.sources))
  ));
};
sourceRequest('in').then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you just need a step that *replaces* the list of responses with the list of sources.

```
const promisedSources = Promise.all(promisesCollection)
                          .then(responses => 
                              responses.map(response => response.data.sources)
                          );
return promisesSources;
```